# find if string has slash in front

Tags: c#, string, indexof, backslash

I want to find if a string has "/" in front of it, in my code I get indexof of the string and find out if the character before it has anything, which works but how do I find if it actually is forward slash. here is my code:

```
 string test = "/images/";

            if (test.IndexOf(@"images/") - 1 == -1)
            {

            }
```

**EDIT**

Some of my strings may have full url and some may be as above and some may not have / at all hence using index of

Comment: You may use a `Regex.Match()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
if (test.StartsWith("/"))
```

? (It's not clear what your sample code is trying to achieve.)

Note that "/" is a forward-slash, not a backslash - and you don't need the verbatim string literal in your case, given that the string doesn't contain any backslashes or line breaks.

EDIT: Your question isn't clear, but I suspect you want something like:

```
int index = test.IndexOf(targetString);
if (index > 0 && test[index - 1] == '/')
{
    // There's a leading forward slash. Deal with it appropriately
}
```

Comment: @Sam1: Your question isn't clear. I'll edit with what I *think* you mean, but it really isn't clear.

Comment: basically my string may conatin a full url or an image url so if i find full url fine and if i find just image in string and before the string image there is no forward slash then replace it with full url. hope it is clear

Comment: @Sam1: Not really, to be honest. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - but hopefully my answer helps anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Method StartsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx):

```
    if(test.StartsWith("/"))
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (test.StartsWith("images") ||
    test.IndexOf("/images") > -1 ||
    test.IndexOf("\\images") > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many good answers :)

Anyway, I meant to say the following:

```
string str = "/\images\///";
Match matchfirstFwdSlash = Regex.Match(str, "^[\\/]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (matchfirstFwdSlash.Success)
   {MessageBox .Show ("Success","Success");}
else
   {MessageBox .Show ("Oops","Oops");}
```

Answer (score -1):

//You can find this way

```
 string test = "/Images/";

        string a = test.Split('/')[0];

        if (a=="")
        {

        }
```

Comment: If you're splitting by "/", the value will never be "/"... and why would you call `ToString` on a string?